# Excel column data match and replace

Tags: excel

I have the need to match two columns between two sheets and replace a third column's data with another.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
If Sheet1.ColumnA = Sheet2.ColumnA
Then replace Sheet1.ColumnE with Sheet2.ColumnC
```

I'm sure this is simple with VLOOKUP or something, but Excel isn't my strong suit.

Comment: Are you referring to matching individual rows or actually the whole column? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you look at MSDN's page for [VLOOKUP()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)?  It can explain the usage much better than we can.  It even has a video.

Comment: Yes match individual rows within those columns. I'll check out some more VLOOKUP usage information. I've done this a long time ago, but am always lost when I try it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to do a vlookup in the columns described, this should work

Assuming your data starts in row 2, in Sheet1 cell E2: `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$6,3,FALSE)`

Update range to make sure it covers all the data you need.  E.g. change `$C$6` to `$C$100` if you have 100 rows of data.